# How to export dropdown list(with options) from JSON to excel in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, excel, typescript, exceljs

I am trying to export JSON data to excel which has a dropdown list.

Is it possible to create the dropdown(with options) in excel if we pass an array as a cell value?

I am trying to use the inbuilt library XLSX to achieve this but not able to see data if I pass the array in the cell value.

**Update: Jack Provided one library ExcelJS that supports the data validation but needs to do some configurations for that.**

Is there any Angular Library that supports this feature?

Below is an example of the project which I tried. I would like to append multiple sheets based on data passed to the service and names of sheets will be taken from the objects.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx-b4al4p

Comment: unfortunately I have never used xlsx library. I have tried to go through the docs on how to add validation using the library but I seem not to find anything. I believe the solution is around adding validation but how to do it I have no clue

Comment: Are there any other libraries that support data validation?

Comment: Currently I unfortunately do not have any suggestion

Comment: @Owen Found one library (ExcelJS) which supports this but needs to manipulate data to be sent.

Comment: I recommend this post, it works using the same library XLSX https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149667/how-to-add-data-validation-list-in-excel-using-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an addition to @ZackReam solution with a focus on your current scenario

To begin, we first define a data structure

```json
  workbookData = [
    {
      workSheet: "data 1",
      rows: [
        { eid: "1", ename: "John", esal: ["val 1", "val2", "val 3"] },
        { eid: "4", ename: "Parker", esal: ["val 1", "val2", "val 3"] },
        { eid: "5", ename: "Iron", esal: ["val 1", "val2", "val 3"] }
      ]
    },
    {
      workSheet: "data 2",
      rows: [
        { eid: "9", ename: "Doe", esal: ["val 1", "val2", "val 3"] },
        { eid: "10", ename: "Peter", esal: ["val 1", "val2", "val 3"] },
        { eid: "11", ename: "Man", esal: ["val 1", "val2", "val 3"] }
      ]
    }
```

Next we define a service to generate a workbook dynamically from the above data

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as FileSaver from "file-saver";
import * as ExcelJS from "exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js";

const EXCEL_TYPE =
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8";
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = ".xlsx";

@Injectable()
export class ExcelService {
  constructor() {}

  public async exportAsExcelFile(workbookData: any[], excelFileName: string) {
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

    workbookData.forEach(({ workSheet, rows }) => {
      const sheet = workbook.addWorksheet(workSheet);
      const uniqueHeaders = [
        ...new Set(
          rows.reduce((prev, next) => [...prev, ...Object.keys(next)], [])
        )
      ];
      sheet.columns = uniqueHeaders.map(x => ({ header: x, key: x }));

      rows.forEach((jsonRow, i) => {
        let cellValues = { ...jsonRow };

        uniqueHeaders.forEach((header, j) => {
          if (Array.isArray(jsonRow[header])) {
            cellValues[header] = "";
          }
        });
        sheet.addRow(cellValues);
        uniqueHeaders.forEach((header, j) => {
          if (Array.isArray(jsonRow[header])) {
            const jsonDropdown = jsonRow.esal;
            sheet.getCell(
              this.getSpreadSheetCellNumber(i + 1, j)
            ).dataValidation = {
              type: "list",
              formulae: [`"${jsonDropdown.join(",")}"`]
            };
          }
        });
      });
    });

    const buffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
    this.saveAsExcelFile(buffer, excelFileName);
  }

  private getSpreadSheetCellNumber(row, column) {
    let result = "";

    // Get spreadsheet column letter
    let n = column;
    while (n >= 0) {
      result = String.fromCharCode((n % 26) + 65) + result;
      n = Math.floor(n / 26) - 1;
    }

    // Get spreadsheet row number
    result += `${row + 1}`;

    return result;
  }

  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(
      data,
      fileName + "_export_" + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION
    );
  }
}
```

The service will dynamically determine the headers and the columns to set as validation

### Transforming the data

We can transform your data to this structure using below

```
  transform (data) {
    const noOfRowaToGenerate = 10;
    return data.map(({name, values}) => {
      const headers = values.reduce((prev, next) => 
        ({...prev, [next.header]: Array.isArray
        (next.value) ? next.value.map(({name}) => name): next.value}), {})
      return {
        workSheet: name,
        rows: Array(noOfRowaToGenerate).fill(headers)
      }
    })
  }
   workbookData = this.transform(this.data1)
```

Below is a sample demo

[**Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exceljs-sample)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Owen.. just wondering what changes I need to do to support the structure like this where the header is coming from object  data1: any = [
    {
      name: "data1", //sheet1 with name data1
      values: [
        { header: "eid", value: "" },
        { header: "test", value: [{ name: "test1" }, { name: "test2" }] },
        { header: "ename", value: "" },
        { header: "esal", value: [{ name: "val" }, { name: "val1" }] }
      ]
    }
  ];

Comment: Will have a look in the morning and get back

Comment: this is a very good solution for the Bravo issue

Comment: Hi Owen, Can you please help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67571001/how-to-add-frozen-columns-to-primeng-when-rows-are-rendering-dynamically-in-angu

Answer (score 2):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/387#issuecomment-390504612) in **SheetJS** (package: `xlsx`), data validation is a pro-only feature.

> We offer this in the [Pro compendium](https://sheetjs.com/pro). Since companies have paid for the features already, it would be unfair to them if we turned around and made it available as open source.

---

Another library you could check out is [**ExcelJS**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) (package: `exceljs`). It [runs in the browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#browser) and [has support for data validation](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#data-validations).
You would have to do a bit of manual mapping of your data to get your data in the format that the library expects, but it is possible.

[Here is an example Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular6-export-xlsx?file=src/app/services/excel.service.ts)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Just One question if I have a data structure like, How I can create excel dynamically based on the value have an array of objects?  data: any = [
    {
      header: "eid",
      value: ""
    },
    {
      header: "test",
      value: [
        {
          name: "test1"
        },
        {
          name: "test2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      header: "ename",
      value: ""
    },
    {
      header: "esal",
      value: [
        {
          name: "val"
        },
        {
          name: "val1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

Comment: In this example excel header will as eid,test,ename, and esal and next row have dropdown validations if the value has an array.

Comment: @Bravo I have checked demo provided by ZackReam and it is working fantastically. How would you like me to help?

Comment: I have modified data where object have header and data and dropdown values (if available) as well as multiple sheets.

Comment: It is available in my stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

You can try do it
this works using the same library **exceljs** and **filesaver.js** from you example

```
import { Workbook } from 'exceljs';
import * as fs from 'file-saver';
generateExcel(list,header) {
  let data:any = [];
  for(let i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    let arr = [list[i].requisitionId,list[i].applicationid, list[i].candidateid, list[i].unitcode];
    data.push(arr);
  }
  console.log(data);
  //Create workbook and worksheet
  let workbook = new Workbook();
  let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Candidate Report');

  //Add Header Row
  let headerRow = worksheet.addRow(header);

  // Cell Style : Fill and Border
  headerRow.eachCell((cell, number) => {
    cell.fill = {
      type: 'pattern',
      pattern: 'solid',
      fgColor: { argb: 'FFFFFF00' },
      bgColor: { argb: 'FF0000FF' }
    }
    cell.border = { top: { style: 'thin' }, left: { style: 'thin' }, bottom: { style: 'thin' }, right: { style: 'thin' } }
  })
  worksheet.getColumn(3).width = 30;
  data.forEach(d => {
    let row = worksheet.addRow(d);
  }
  );
  list.forEach((element,index) =>{
    worksheet.getCell('E'+(+index+2)).dataValidation = {
      type: 'list',
      allowBlank: true,
      formulae: ['"Selected,Rejected,On-hold"']
  };
  })
  //Generate Excel File with given name
  workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data) => {
    let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
    fs.saveAs(blob, 'candidate.xlsx');
  })

}
```

My reference is this
[How to add data validation list in excel using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149667/how-to-add-data-validation-list-in-excel-using-javascript)