# How to add frozen columns to primeNG when rows are rendering dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I was looking for help to add the frozen columns feature in my primeng table where the columns and rows are dynamically rendered.

I do have a config( **isPK: true**) that came from data on which I want to make frozen columns.

I have tried following stackblitz but I cannot found a solution to match the example given in the documentation of PrimeNG

Thanks, @Owen for the answer but now If I try to add an extra column in the HTML itself it is getting doubled like this,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablescroll-demo-jvmrfs
[image]

Comment: Do you mean, non editable? if yes, then you can provide value to cell but in non-edited mode. Ex. The pInputText that you used can be in disabled mode on certain conditions.

Comment: No Frozen columns https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use templating for frozen data as described in documentation in [Templates](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table) section:

> frozenheader: Content of the thead element in frozen side.

> frozenbody: Content of the tbody element in frozen side.

Here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablescroll-demo-s8q6xl?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Table body looks weird but because you are using dynamic columns, there must be a match between columns and data.

Like this example for [Dynamic columns](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/dynamic) from documentation.

Comment: Why template is necessary?
 alignFrozen="left"  
        pFrozenColumn 
        [frozen]="true">  for dynamic columns doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: I get Can't bind to 'frozen' since it isn't a known property of 'th'

Answer (score 2):

Its sometimes easier to move from a working example and generate what you want step after another. Something like below

```html
<p-button class="secondary" label="Add row" (onClick)="onAddRow(card)"></p-button>


<p-table #dt [columns]="scrollableCols" [frozenColumns]="frozenCols" [value]="card" [scrollable]="true"
  scrollHeight="200px" frozenWidth="200px">
  <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
    <colgroup>
      <col *ngFor="let col of columns" style="width:200px">
    </colgroup>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
        {{col.header}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let tr of card[0].rows; let i = index">
      <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let attr of card[0].attributes; let j = index">
          <td
            [ngClass]="{'error-block': 
                                                            (card[0].rows[i].validated == true && isSubmitted && card[0].rows[i][j].value === '' && card[0].rows[i][j].required === 'true') ||
                                                            (card[0].rows[i].validated == true && isSubmitted && card[0].rows[i][j].value.length < card[0].rows[i][j].minLength)}">
            <ng-container *ngIf="attr.type === 'string'">
              <input pInputText style="width: 100%;"
                                                                    (ngModelChange)="onChange($event, i, j, card)"
                                                                    type="text"
                                                                    [(ngModel)]="card[0].rows[i][j].value"
                                                                    [maxlength]="card[0].rows[i][j].maxLength"
                                                                    [minlength]="card[0].rows[i][j].minLength"/>
              <span class="error required-error" *ngIf="card[0].rows[i].validated == true && isSubmitted && card[0].rows[i][j].value === '' && card[0].rows[i][j].required === 'true'">
                                                                    <!-- This field is required. -->
                                                                </span>
              <span class="error minlength-error" *ngIf="card[0].rows[i].validated == true && isSubmitted && card[0].rows[i][j].value.length < card[0].rows[i][j].minLength">
                                                                    <!-- Please enter {{card[0].rows[i][j].minLength}} characters to continue. -->
                                                                </span>
              <!-- {{i}}, {{j}} {{card[0].rows[i][j] | json}} -->
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="attr.values">
              <select class="dropdown" [(ngModel)]="card[0].rows[i][j].value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event, i, j, card)">
                                                                    <option *ngFor="let option of attr.values">{{option}}</option>
                                                                </select>
              <span class="error required-error" *ngIf="card[0].rows[i].validated == true && isSubmitted && card[0].rows[i][j].value === '' && card[0].rows[i][j].required === 'true'">
                                                                    <!-- This field is required. -->
                                                                </span>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="attr.type === 'date'">
              <p-calendar [readonlyInput]="true" panelStyleClass="datepicker" appendTo="body"
                inputStyleClass="date-input" [(ngModel)]="card[0].rows[i][j].value"
                (ngModelChange)="onChange($event, i, j, card)" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy"></p-calendar>
            </ng-container>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

[**See Demo Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablescroll-demo-hfsr4n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Owen but now if I would like to add an extra column directly in HTML it will be doubled directly like this, https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablescroll-demo-jvmrfs

Answer (score 2):

I added a property **isFrozenColumn** in the column definition like that and it worked perfectly 
See ***Frozen Columns*** parte in https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/scroll

```
columns = [
        {
            field: 'name',
            header: 'Name',
            isFrozenColumn: true
        },
        {
            field: 'Phone',
            header: 'phone',
            isFrozenColumn: false
        }]
```

***Header***

```
<th alignFrozen="left"  
        pFrozenColumn 
        [frozen]="true">Actions</th>
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">
    <th class="width-small"
        alignFrozen="left"  
        pFrozenColumn 
        [frozen]="col?.isFrozenColumn">
        <p-header>{{ col.header }}</p-header>
    </th>
</ng-container>
```

***Body***

```
<td alignFrozen="left"  
        pFrozenColumn 
        [frozen]="true">
    <a type="button" 
        (click)="edit(item)">Edit</a>
    </td>
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">
    <td alignFrozen="left"  
        pFrozenColumn 
        [frozen]="col?.isFrozenColumn">
        {{ item[col.field] }}
    </td>
</ng-container>
```